How to calculate cumulative Q2 in OPLS-DA
In SIMCA User Guide, $p.450$, cumulative $Q^2$ is calculated by:
$$
Q^2(\text{cum})=1−∏_{a=1}^{N_\text{comp}} \left( \frac{PRESS}{SS} \right)_a \tag{1}
$$
where $∏_{a=1}^{N_\text{comp}}(PRESS/SS)_a$ is the product of $PRESS/SS$ for each individual component $a$.
This confused me. An OPLS model is expressed as (see introduction here):
$$
X=t_1p_1^T+T_OP_O^T+E \tag2
$$
or by J. Trygg's paper
$$
X=T_pP_p^T+T_OP_O^T+E \tag3
$$
and a new $y$ is predicted from predictive components.
From my understanding, the

each individual component $a$

should refer to the predictive components, since all predictions should be from the $X$ corrected by orthogonal scores $T_O$ and loadings $P_O$, i.e., $X_P=X-T_OP_O^T$. Cross validation is used to determine the number of orthogonal components. Therefore, for new matrix $X_\text{new}$, it is corrected by orthogonal components as well, and then used to perform the prediction using predictive components. But based on equation $(2)$, the number of predictive components is 1. The question is how to calculate $PRESS/SS$ for each individual component $a$ here?
If I was wrong, I should try to obtain both number of orthogonal components and predictive components using a single cross validation loop. This means that, for each number of orthogonal components (e.g., from 1 to 15), I should go through each number of predictive components (e.g., from 1 to 15), so that both number of orthogonal components and predictive components can be determined (total $15^2=225$ loops should be tried in each cross validation iteration if the max number of orthogonal and predictive components is $15$). But I'm not sure whether this is correct as this procedure is a bit complex, and I can't find any materials mentioned this.
So how to correctly understand the term

each individual component $a$

and correctly calculate $Q^2(\text{cum})$?
